# Old HDD reformatt issue

Tags: disk-format, hdd

So I have a HDD I want to format to use with my Mac. I think the portion Microsoft basic data is probably some kind of boot drive.

How do i delete it?

This is the return from terminal 
It’s disk2s2 that I'm struggling to remove

```
  /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER 

   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2

   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk2s1

   2:       Microsoft Basic Data                         -187715584 B  disk2s2

   3:                  Apple_HFS UNTITLED                21.0 MB    disk2s3

   4:                  Apple_HFS UNTITLED                939.5 MB   disk2s4

   5:                  Apple_HFS                         939.5 MB   disk2s5

   6:                  Apple_HFS                         939.5 MB   disk2s6

   7:                  Apple_HFS                         939.5 MB   disk2s7

   8:                  Apple_HFS                         939.5 MB   disk2s8

   9:                  Linux LVM                         4.0 TB     disk2s9
```

Update.

After attempting to partition the whole disk, this was the results:

```
QueenC$ diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 1 GPT HFS+ MacintoshHD 100% 
Started partitioning on disk2 Unmounting 
disk Error: -69877: Couldn't open device (Is a disk in use by a storage 
system such as AppleRAID, CoreStorage, or APFS?)
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do?  Erase the entire drive or remove a single partition?  The text in the question conflicts with the title.  Have you tried using Disk Utility (in the Utilities folder)?  What were the results?

Comment: I want to use the drive as an external back up.     wanted to remove the partition.yes I’ve tried using disk utility if i formats the whole drive it just sits saying partitioning (i had it for 4 hours first time before i quit) i cannot format the partition either it returns the error (The chosen size is not valid for the chosen file system.
Operation failed…)

Comment: And Ive tried choosing partition the whole disk utility crashes !

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297788/119271

Comment: QueenC$ diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 1 GPT HFS+ MacintoshHD 100%
Started partitioning on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
(Is a disk in use by a storage system such as AppleRAID, CoreStorage, or APFS?)

Comment: Issue the command `sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m`.  This will wipe the entire drive.  Once it's finished, issue the previous `diskutil` command again.

Comment: dd: /dev/rdisk2: Resource busy 
distil list returns the same output

Comment: Try:  `sudo diskutil unmountDisk disk2` then the `dd` command

Comment: is there a way i can merge the remaining usable partitions 3 to 7 to at least create a space I can use as one  ?

Comment: no game it returned >  sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.000031 secs (0 bytes/sec)

Comment: Your drive may be failing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Disk Utility from /Applications/Utilities.
2. Choose View → Show All Devices.
3. Select your external disk device in the sidebar.
4. Choose Erase in the toolbar.
5. Enter a name for the disk and choose a partition type such as Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
6. Click Erase.

Comment: have tried sudo  diskutil  eraseVolume  jhfs+  MyVolume  disk2, it won’t unmount> then unmounted still the same.