# MBP Not Booting After Attempted Deletion of Ubuntu Partition

Tags: macos, partition, dual-boot, grub

I have a MBP (late 2011 I believe, running 10.12) that I had setup to run macOS and Ubuntu. I am using rEFId.  I don't use Ubuntu much so I went to delete the partition last night. When I did that, via disk utility, I had an error stating the disk needed to be repaired in safe mode (or something like that). After I tried repairing in safe mode, I am now no longer able to boot into macOS or Ubuntu. I get a GNU GRUB screen when I turn on the computer  and a weird [error screen](https://i.imgur.com/Y71DVqy.jpg) after I input "exit".

After using `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show disk0`, I found that one of the partitions (the one with the macOS) was being identified as type FFFF... I followed some instructions on here and was able to correct [that](https://i.imgur.com/CIAxHEA.jpg), but I still do not have that partition available to boot with when on the Mac boot screen (when I hold option down at start up).

I have noticed that my LV is not staying mounted. I have unlocked it and mounted it multiple times and run volume checks on everything with no problems. 
Just can't seem to get the Mac SSD available to boot on.

I would really like to get back into macOS as I haven't backed up in a few weeks. :(

Is there anything else I can do to possibly fix this??

Here are some terminal outputs.

[gpt -r show](https://i.imgur.com/jFm9iKM.jpg)

[diskutil list](https://i.imgur.com/FjBxc7y.jpg)

Comment: You should be able to boot into Internet Recovery - `Cmd-Option-R`.  If you can do that, erase & repartition your drive.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297788/119271  This will make it "100% Apple." It will be an HFS+ partion ready for a clean macOS install.  rEFInd will be removed so you won't have any issues booting.

Comment: I believe `disk0s3` is suppose to by type `Apple_Boot`. You show the type to be `Apple_HFS`. In other words, you show `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` where I would assume `426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` is suppose to appear.